# Assigning a single key to all similar products/rows in a data frame based on product description and one other key

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Based on 3 keys/columns uniqueid , uniqueid2 and uniqueid3 I need to generate a column new_key that will tag all associated products/rows with a single key.

````
 ```python 
   df = pd.DataFrame({'uniqueid': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 
                                    4: 'd', 5: 'd', 6: 'e', 7: 'e',8:'g',9:'g',10:'h',11:'l',12:'m'},
'uniqueid2': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 
                                    4: 'd', 5: 'd', 6: 'e', 7: 'e',8:'g',9:'g',10:'h',11:'l',12:'l'},
                       'uniqueid3': {0: 'z', 1: 'y', 2: 'x', 3: 'y', 
                                     4: 'x', 5: 'v', 6: 'x', 7: 'u',8:'h',9:'i',10:'k',11:'k',12:'n'}})
```
````

Data that I have based on columns uniqueid ,uniqueid2 and uniqueid3. I need to create new_key as already there. Here in this dummy data all the rows except first belong to a same product based on associations in column 1 and column2.

But I am unsure on how to proceed further. Quick help needed please

```
Expected Output:


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAl56.png
```

Comment: Please post data in text format instead pictures.

Comment: @neha I have edited your question with input and expected output in copy/pastable format. Please correct if it is wrong. Also, see my answer.

Comment: Your problem statement looks like a network problem , consider using [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/) after instaling it ,see if my answer helps

Comment: @anky: your solution is working absolutely fine. Thanks a lot. Just checking real data I realized I will  need to add one more column. Can you please help me modify this solution for 3 columns?uniqueId uniqueId2 uniqueId3 new_key
a a z a
b b y b
b b x b
c c y b
d d x b
d d v b
e e x b
e e u b
g g h g
g g i g
h h k h
l l k h
m l n h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a `networkx` problem, lets try:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
#get first value of uniqueid based on uniqueid2
s = df.groupby('uniqueid2')['uniqueid'].transform('first')
#get connected components from unique id and the above variable s
G.add_edges_from(df[['uniqueid']].assign(k=s).to_numpy().tolist())
cc = list(nx.connected_components(G))
#[{'a'}, {'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}, {'g'}, {'h', 'l'}]

idx = [dict.fromkeys(y,x) for x, y in enumerate(cc)]
d={k: v for d in idx for k, v in d.items()}
df['new_key'] = s.groupby(s.map(d)).transform('first')
```

---

```
print(df)

   uniqueid uniqueid2 new_key
0         a         z       a
1         b         y       b
2         b         x       b
3         c         y       b
4         d         x       b
5         d         v       b
6         e         x       b
7         e         u       b
8         g         h       g
9         g         i       g
10        h         k       h
11        l         k       h
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. Its working fine. I have a question, will it work fine for 3 columns as well.

Comment: @neha Hi, iterative debugging is generally discouraged in Stack Overflow, if my solution answer the question you had posted, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) and upvoting the answer, and kindly post a fresh question with 3 columns and the expected output. Me or other contributors can take a look and propose a solution

Comment: Thanks for your  suggestion. I have accepted the answer and created a new question with 3 columns. Request you to look into this if possible

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the correct output, but I'm not sure this is exactly what you want to do in order to generate the `new_key` column. This solution checks `uniqueid2` to see if all values are unique within each `uniqueid` group as well as the entire `uniqueid2` column..

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'uniqueid': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 
                                4: 'd', 5: 'd', 6: 'e', 7: 'e',8:'g',9:'g',10:'h',11:'l'},
                   'uniqueid2': {0: 'z', 1: 'y', 2: 'x', 3: 'y', 
                                 4: 'x', 5: 'v', 6: 'x', 7: 'u',8:'h',9:'i',10:'k',11:'k'}})
df['m1'] = (df.groupby('uniqueid2')['uniqueid2'].transform('count') == 1)
df['m2'] = (df.groupby('uniqueid')['m1'].transform(sum))
df['m3'] = (df.groupby('uniqueid')['uniqueid2'].transform('size'))
df['m4'] = (df.groupby('uniqueid')['uniqueid'].transform('count') == 1) 
df['new_key'] = np.where((df['m2'] == df['m3']) | df['m4'], df['uniqueid'], 'b')
df
Out[13]: 
   uniqueid uniqueid2     m1   m2  m3     m4 new_key
0         a         z   True  1.0   1   True       a
1         b         y  False  0.0   2  False       b
2         b         x  False  0.0   2  False       b
3         c         y  False  0.0   1   True       c
4         d         x  False  1.0   2  False       b
5         d         v   True  1.0   2  False       b
6         e         x  False  1.0   2  False       b
7         e         u   True  1.0   2  False       b
8         g         h   True  2.0   2  False       g
9         g         i   True  2.0   2  False       g
10        h         k  False  0.0   1   True       h
11        l         k  False  0.0   1   True       l
```

I kept `m1`, `m2` and `m3`, so that you could see the progression of the logic. You can drop these columns with:

`df = df.drop(['m1','m2','m3'], axis=1)`

Comment: @ David: Thanks for your reply. This is not what I am looking for. I have changed my data and required output to explain what I need. I need to tag all similar together based on uniqueid or uniqueid2 and create a new_key that's a single key for all similar products( this key can be same unique id or uniueid2 or any other randomly generated key)

Comment: @neha Please check now. I think I understand now.

Comment: @ David : I have added more rows to make my problem clear and added to Expected output as well